# Using enums in Visual Studio 2010 Table Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, database-design, sqlmetal

I'm designing a data base using the Table Designer in VS 2010 pro, then generating code with SqlMetal.

I want to use a `enum` as a type in one of the columns.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Convert to Enum as described in [Enum Support - EF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772.aspx):

- create new model
- add new Entity
- convert it nu Enum

*Update*

You need to Entity Framework 5.0, .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012

It is not possible under you condition with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If I understood right, this will only work on .NET framework 4.5, and there for worn't work out for me, [because VS2010 doesn't support .NET 4.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ab8782d-36f5-4b7a-a264-c68f2dd564f9/targeting-net-45-with-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @elyashiv - yor are right - its Feature of EF 5.0  Can you update you project for Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: @elyashiv - and also "Enum support was introduced in Entity Framework 5." You can use Entity Framework 5 with Visual Studio 2010 - so try it please.

Comment: from the link you provided: "Enum support was introduced in Entity Framework 5. To use the new features like enums, spatial data types, and table-valued functions, **you must target .NET Framework 4.5.**"

Comment: @elyashiv - yes I have read it too - thats why my proposal for you is to **try it**

Comment: Doesn't work. not surprising when it is written in the [official site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx) it won't.

Comment: @elyashiv - and upgrade to 2012 is not possible?

Comment: @elyashiv - I have updated my answer. Negative answer can also be a solution